# Migrate from SQLAzure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I was wondering if there were any resources available that provide information on Migrating a Database and its schema / data out of SQL Azure and back to a nice cozy sql server

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By far the best is Red Gate's SQL Compare. V9 is in free public beta, works like a charm. Highly recommend for back n forth migrations